# Join two pairs of columns and eliminate duplicates into two columns

Tags: google-sheets

I need to join two pairs of column into two columns (not just one) and eliminate duplicates.

Take a look a this capture to see what I mean. I need to join yellow and blue cells to get the result in the green cells.

I tried with UNIQUE but it only accepts one argument, then I don't see how to add the second pair of columns.

The closest I get is this `=CONCATENATE(UNIQUE(A3:B7);UNIQUE(D3:E5))` but I get all values in just one cell. Not what I need.

You can also take a look a this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-x5KINErYKgwxgv5ZCpxbGdxRdp6NBDWMK2Cxhl5Xy8/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=UNIQUE({A3:B7;D3:E6})
```

Using curly quotes `{}` we create an array. Using `;` we place these values one under the other and we then use unique.

Comment: Awesome! Simple. Works!

Comment: Glad I could help :)